# Expectation in joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

The joint probability density function (joint pdf) of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is:

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}
\frac{6 - x - y}8&\text{if } 0 < x < 2 \text{ and } 2 < y < 4\\
0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Determine $E(X)$ and $P(X + Y < 3)$

I'm a little unsure on how to approach this. Any help would really be appreciated, since i'm unsure what the proper methods are with joint pdf compared to regular singular pdf.

EDIT: I ended finding $E(X)$ as $0.833$. I just integrated with respect to $dy$ and then then integrated that answer times $x$ with respect to $dx$. Still stuck on part 2 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^2x\left[\int_2^4\frac{6-x-y}{8}dy\right]dx=\dots=\frac{5}{6}$$

$$\mathbb{P}[X+Y<3]=\int_0^1\left[\int_2^{3-x}\frac{6-x-y}{8}dy  \right]dx=\dots=\frac{5}{24}$$

here is a useful drawing to explain the correct integral bounds

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got it haha

Answer (score 0):

The expectation you found is correct. The expectation of a function $g(X,Y)$ of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ is

$$\mathrm E[g(X,Y)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ denotes the joint density; you're taking $g(X,Y)=X$.

---

There are several ways to compute $P(X+Y<3)$. The simplest would be to just integrate the joint density over the given region, which is a triangular subset $T$ of the square $[0,2]\times[2,4]$, specifically the set

$$T=\left\{(x,y)\mid0\le x\le1\text{ and }2\le y\le3-x\right\}$$

(or with $2\le y\le3$ and $0\le x\le3-y$).

Then

$$P(X+Y<3)=\iint_T f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I just computed this and got 0.2083 as a final answer! I just have a question. I get why the limit of y becomes 3-x, but I don't understand why the max limit of x changes from 2 to 1? Same case for the alternative option, where the limit of y foes from 4 to 3.

Comment: I must have been holding my hand a smidge too far to the left... Fixed

Comment: Wait but it was originally correct, no? When I put in 0.2083 as an answer, it said it was correct but now when I'm computing this integral, I'm getting 0.04166 as an answer and that's apparently wrong?

Comment: It sounds like what I initially had was correct. tommik's plot shows exactly why. $\frac5{24}$ is the correct probability.